# How to retrieve data from child cells EXCEL

Tags: excel, database-design, excel-formula, foreign-key-relationship

I want to retrieve all items within a specific column of a table.

In this scenario, I have 2 tables, The first table contains a primary key, and the second table contains a foreign key. a 1 to many relationship is set up for the tables respectively.

I want a function/way of retrieving all items within a column in table 2 that has a foreign key that matches the primary key in table 1.

One way of doing this is through a VLOOKUP, though surely through using DAX, or some other function set, I can exploit the relationship I have made in the DataModel to make this easier for me to do.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just get the required data from the DB with a proper SELECT statement? Something like

```
SELECT column
FROM t1, t2
WHERE t1.key = t2.fkey 
  AND t1.key = 'whatever you search for';
```

Then you should get the data you want.

Comment: you can do this in Microsoft excel?

Comment: Most probably not.
But when you talk about 1-m-relationships I thought your retieve the data from a DB.

If this is not the case, it would be good to have an idea what you want to achieve.
Do you want to add up the column, you might use a SUMIF, if copy you might use a filter.
Both can be used in macros.